# Curve offset caused by missing part of the data for flutter fl_chart

Tags: flutter

Everyone is advanced, I am currently using fl_chart in flutter, I hope to use isCurved:true, but the Curve is offset due to the lack of time series data I prepared, but when isCurve:false, the line graph is normal. Is there a way to use the curve function when some data is missing?
[curve:false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GJIb.png)
[curve:true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5F27.png)

```
Widget bottomTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 16,
    );
    final DateTime date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(value.toInt());
    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      child: Text(
        DateFormat.Hm().format(date),
        style: style,
      ),
    );
}
LineChartBarData(
  spots: _values,
  barWidth: 2,
  isStrokeCapRound: false,
  isCurved: true, 
  dotData: const FlDotData(show: false),
  belowBarData: BarAreaData(
    show: true,
  ),
);

data:
[
{
  "title": "1",
  "time": "2023-06-24T09:13:42",
  "params": [
    {
      "value": "32.3"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "2",
  "time": "2023-06-24T09:14:12",
  "params": [
    {
      "value": "26.5"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "3",
  "time": "2023-06-24T10:57:39",
  "params": [
    {
      "value": "33.4"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "4",
  "time": "2023-06-24T10:58:09",
  "params": [
    {
      "value": "33.4"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Fill in missing data

Most of the code is based on the official pub, but when using the curve, it is found that there are a lot of gaps in the data, which makes the curve have problems.